# R shiny app interactive photo gallery - not able to access multiple files at once?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to write an R shiny app that, given a directory of image files, takes user input and decides which images to display on the page. The number of images may vary depending on the user's input. I have chosen to reach this goal using a "lookup table", a CSV file that contains the name of all the image file paths as one column and a filtering column that matches the user's input. I have a directory called "IMAGES_" with three PNG files, and my lookup table ("LOOKUP_.csv") looks like this.
[image]

Here is the shiny app I have written to try and accomplish this:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

lookup_files = read_csv("LOOKUP_.csv")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Images"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("label", label = "Choose a label...", choices = unique(lookup_files$label)),
      br(),
      actionButton("showImage", "Show Image(s)")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("imageDisplay")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$showImage, {
    all_files = lookup_files %>% dplyr::filter(label == input$label)
    N_IMGS = nrow(all_files)
    
    output$imageDisplay = renderUI({
      lapply(seq_len(N_IMGS), function(i) {
        imageOutput(paste0("this_", i))
      })
    })
    
    for (i in seq_len(N_IMGS)) {
      output[[paste0("this_", i)]] <- renderImage(list(src = all_files$file[i], width = 400), deleteFile = FALSE)
    }
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This almost works perfectly. It gives a drop-down and automatically identifies all possible values for "label", such that the user cannot select erroneous values. When you click a button labeled "Show Image(s)", it then displays the images. The problem is that for label "B", which has two available images (plot2.png and plot3.png), it displays plot3.png twice instead of plot2.png and plot3.png. It may just be a silly bug but I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas here. Maybe this is not even the best way to accomplish my desired goal at all, and I'd be happy to hear any alternate suggestions too!

I am running R 4.3.2 with the shiny 1.8.0 package on Windows 11 x64. Please let me know if any additional info is required.

Answer (score 0):

If you change `for` loop with `lapply` it works -

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

lookup_files = read_csv("LOOKUP.csv")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Images"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("label", label = "Choose a label...", choices = unique(lookup_files$label)),
      br(),
      actionButton("showImage", "Show Image(s)")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("imageDisplay")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$showImage, {
    all_files = lookup_files %>% dplyr::filter(label == input$label)
    N_IMGS = nrow(all_files)
    
    output$imageDisplay = renderUI({
      lapply(seq_len(N_IMGS), function(i) {
        imageOutput(paste0("this_", i))
      })
    })
    
    lapply(seq_len(N_IMGS), function(i) {
      output[[paste0("this_", i)]] <- renderImage(list(src = all_files$file[i], width = 400), deleteFile = FALSE)
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have used some random images to generate below output.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the image paths in a reactive and directly render the images inside `renderUI()`.

Here is a reprex:

```r
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

lookup_files <- readr::read_csv("LOOKUP_.csv")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Images"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        inputId = "label",
        label = "Choose a label...",
        choices = unique(lookup_files$label)
      ),
      br(),
      actionButton(inputId = "showImage", label = "Show Image(s)"),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput(outputId = "imageDisplay")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  r_img_paths <- reactive({
    lookup_files |>
      dplyr::filter(label %in% input$label) |>
      dplyr::pull(file)
  }) |> bindEvent(input$showImage)

  output$imageDisplay <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      lapply(r_img_paths(), function(img_path) {
        renderImage(
          list(src = img_path, width = 400),
          deleteFile = FALSE
        )
      })
    )
  }) |> bindEvent(input$showImage)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```